# Risks involved in allowing users to upload json files to the server side

Tags: node.js, security

I'm working on a project that has a feature that allows users to submit and upload their work to the server side as JSON files..are there any security risks involved with that like hijacking/injection? and how can i prevent them?

i'm using Node.JS on the server side, are there any packages that can help with this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience whenever we are asking users to upload anything it is dangerous. We are writing manual serialization and it is like after receiving the user's input we convert all risky characters into something else for example convert { to %br% and so on and then desterilize them.
It also depends how you implemented your code , you may also use URL Encode. And you will need to test your code with some invalid data and add proper exception handlers in your code.